# How to edit Git system config hosted by GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I need to test such Git options as **pack.windowMemory** and **pack.packSizeLimit** and that is why I would like to add them to **system** config file of Git which is hosted by GitLab.

I know that in GitLab **.gitconfig** file resides in **/var/opt/gitlab/.gitconfig** but the file is not editable, instead gitlab.rb must be changed - but how? It is not precisely explained how to set mentioned options and some examples are weird, e.g. to set email one must pass user['git_user_email'].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If installed via Omnibus you need to set these Values in the gitlab.rb. Using *gitlab-ctl reconfigure*
will write these Values in your gitconfig. For your specific case you need to set this:

```
omnibus_gitconfig['system'] = { "pack" => ["windowMemory = N", "packSizeLimit = N"]}
```

For more information please refer to [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/8-0-stable/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template#L481) link.

Comment: Thank you, I have already figured out how should I set it. What was misleading is the message in **/var/opt/gitlab/.gitconfig** file:    
    
  
*To change the contents below, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb and run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`*.    
  
  
But even after I edit **gitlab.rb** and run **gitlab-ctl reconfigure**, the *.gitconfig* file stays the same. However, it turned out that different *gitconfig* is edited: **/opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/gitconfig** - that one contains new settings.